# Почтовые рассылки: Фильтр Gmail

Tags: email, amazon

Дорогие друзья.

Кто решил вопрос с этой бедой?

Беда заключается в попадании писем подписанных DKIM в спам. SPF есть.

Текстовые письма попадают в inbox.

Письма не содержащие мой новый домен тоже попадают в inbox.

Answer (score 1):

Долго боролись с этой проблемой.

Сервера белые, т.е. ни в одном чёрном списке никогда не числились.
DKIM/SPF/PTR всё в норме.
От googl'a получили что-то вроде: "Ваш сервер не числится ни в одном белом списке".

После подачи заявки на https://www.dnswl.org/ и добавления наших серверов в списки, с подобными проблемами больше не сталкивались.

Все письма попадают в Inbox!

Удачи!